# functional equations

Tags: functional-equations

Find all solutions $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ satisfying
$$
f(xu-yv, yu+xv)=f(x, y)f(u, v).
$$

Solution of the following equation
$$
f(xu+yv, yu-xv)=f(x, y)f(u, v)
$$
is known as
$$
f(x,y)=m(x^2+y^2),
$$ 
where $m$ is multiplicative function on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The constant function $ f ( x , y ) = 1 $ also satisfies your second functional equation.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** As a complex function $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$, you have $f(zz')=f(z)f(z')$.